# WCF authorization

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

We have made a webservice which manages e-wallets but we have no idea how to authorize our users.

The authenitication is delegated to an identity service wich returns a SOAP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthenticateUserByEmailResponse xmlns="http://services.xxxx.xx/">
      <AuthenticateUserByEmailResult>boolean</AuthenticateUserByEmailResult>
    </AuthenticateUserByEmailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

We've read about BasicHttpBinding and WSHttpBinding but we can't find a similar senario where we just have to worry about authorization.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to get started?

Comment: What can you do and what do you need to do? Can you call your authentication service from a Console application? Do you have the users email? If you have a wsdl, you can use [a tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) to generate client code for you.

Comment: Users have to provide us with their e-mail and password which is stored in the database of the identity service. All we need to know is if the user has authenticated himself with our service when he wants to view his wallet, wants to do transactions etc..

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a scenario for [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx). You will need to do some heavy reading, it's not for the faint of heart.

There's a full example of such a service [for download at Microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Claims-Aware-Web-Service-1d55facc).

Answer (score 1):

WIF or Windows Identity Foundation is a good solution, but if its too heavy, just use Roles-Based Authorization

Article on WCF Roles-Based Authentication:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx

More general article from Microsoft Patterns and Practices on WCF Security:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx